# Disable grouping when click header column in DevExpress's VCL TcxGrid

Tags: delphi, devexpress, vcl, tcxgrid

When clicking on the title column header, `TcxGridDBtableView` automatically groups by that column. I don't want that, I want to order by that column.

I want it to be grouped by that column when accessed by menu (`TcxGridPopupMenu`-> *Goup by this column*).

Comment: Doesn't [the same](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.OptionsColumn.AllowSort.property) exist for the VCL control? For each column set the `OptionsColumn.AllowSort` to `False`?

Comment: What you describe is the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

As @Uli Gerhardt mentioned, your desired behavior is what a `TcxDBGridTableView` will do out of the box. You must have changed the behavior, possibly altering the view's

```
OptionsCustomize.GroupBySorting
```

This will enable exactly what you describe. From the DevExpress help:

> Specifies whether sorting data by a column results in grouping by this
>   column.
>
> Syntax
>
> property GroupBySorting: Boolean;
>
> Description   Enabling the GroupBySorting option allows you to emulate
>   the behavior of MS Outlook 2003. This implies that clicking a column
>   header results in grouping data by the clicked column's values. The
>   previously applied grouping is cleared in such cases. If the
>   GroupBySorting option is disabled, clicking a column header results in
>   sorting data by this column's values.
>
> Note that the GroupBySorting option has no effect if sorting via code.
>
> The default value of the GroupBySorting property is False.

Comment: Thanks Nil!. OptionsCustomize.GroupBySorting is the evil!.
Resolved

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the header, and disable the properties what you do not need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the code below, `SetUpGrid` cancels any grouping already set up on a cxGridDBTableView,
enables column sorting and sorts the view on a Name column.

The `Groupby1Click` method groups/ungroups on a given column in code, by setting its GroupingIndex (see Online Help).

```
procedure TDevexGroupingForm.SetUpGrid;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  try
    cxGrid1DBTableView1.BeginUpdate;

    //  Hide GroupBy panel
    cxGrid1DBTableView1.OptionsView.GroupByBox := False;

    //  Allow column sorting
    cxGrid1DBTableView1.OptionsCustomize.ColumnSorting := True;

    //  Undo any existing grouping e.g. set up in IDE
    for i:= 0 to cxGrid1DBTableView1.ColumnCount - 1 do begin
      cxGrid1DBTableView1.Columns[i].GroupIndex := -1;
    end;

    //  Sort TableView on Name column.  Needs 'Uses dxCore'
    cxGrid1DBTableView1Name.SortOrder := soAscending;

  finally
    cxGrid1DBTableView1.EndUpdate;
  end;

end;

procedure TDevexGroupingForm.Groupby1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ACol : TcxGridDBColumn;
  Index : Integer;
begin

  //  The following code operates on the focused column of a TcxGridDBTableView
  //  If the view is already grouped by that column, it is ungrouped;
  //  Otherwise, the column is added to the (initially empty) list of columns
  //  by which the view is grouped;

  Index := TcxGridTableController(cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.Controller).FocusedColumnIndex;
  if Index < 0 then
    exit;

  ACol := cxGrid1DBTableView1.Columns[Index];
  if ACol = Nil then
    exit;

  if ACol.GroupIndex < 0 then begin
    //  Add ACol to the list of grouped Columns
    ACol.GroupIndex := cxGrid1DBTableView1.GroupedColumnCount + 1;
  end
  else begin
    //  Ungroup on ACol
    ACol.GroupIndex := -1;
  end;
end;
```